# Install ColdFusion 6.1 and 9 on same server

Tags: coldfusion

I have a server with ColdFusion 6.1 already installed sometime back. I already have application running with this version.

Now I want to install ColdFusion version 9 on the same server and also keep the version 6.1. So basically I want to use both.

How shall I proceed with the installation?

Anything specific I need to pay attention to when launching my CF 9 installation in the Server?

Answer (score 0):

You can run them I believe as two separate installations running on different ports, but you obviously not be able to run them both on port 80.

You don't mention if you are using IIS / Apache etc. so perhaps we can help more if you give further detail. You could for example run you existing installation on IIS port 80, and then perhaps run the new version on port 8888 but that is an IIS ISAPI configuration thing I believe. Or you could use the built in CF web server *temporarily* on production. Or you could even install Apache can run CF9 through that on a different port.

But in terms of the server install you shouldn't have any issues.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for your response Ciaran Archer.

Ok let me be clearer.

Actually the CF6.1 is using IIS as web server.

Shall I install the CF9 and Apache 2.2 (both 64 bit version)? I believe I need to install CF9 as J2EE EAR since CF6.1 was already installed using J2EE set-up type.

Note that my server is a 2003 Windows OS.

Thx

Answer (score 0):

IIRC, CF 9 won't run on the version of JRun that's installed with CF 6.1. I think you'll need to install CF 9 with its latest version of JRun, then install CF 6.1 onto that JRun install, both as J2EE installs.

Otherwise, you can keep your CF install as-is and deploy CF 9 on Tomcat (instead of JRun) using port 8080 with or without Apache.